# How would I import z3 solver in pyodide

Tags: javascript, z3, pyodide

I am trying to recreate a python project that uses z3 solver, which is not very supported on JS (especially on html)

I found that I could use pyodide for doing python code and make this project a lot easier. But pyodide doesn't seem to recognise z3 solver as a package.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Z3 has support for JavaScript (via TypeScript), see here: https://microsoft.github.io/z3guide/programming/Z3%20JavaScript%20Examples/

For best compatibility/ease of use, if you're aiming a web-based project, you should use these bindings.

There are further examples here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/tree/master/src/api/js/examples

Comment: But it has a very unclear documentation and how to implement it into my code, could you provide a few examples that uses Z3 JS CDN, thanks in advance

Comment: The link I gave has tons of examples. I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for. Stack-overflow works the best if you post what you tried and where you got stuck. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Examples, yes, there are a lot, but how would I integrate it into a web-based project, it has no mention about linking the package anywhere on the documentation

Comment: Can you add some example code highlighting the problem?

Comment: @ThatTheredstoner I added another link with more examples. Hopefully those'll get you started. Otherwise, please post what you tried and where you get stuck.